# What would be the aftermath of not immediately showing the vote results?

Tags: discussion, voting, user-interface, user-experience, polling

Few polls on the internet show the results before letting you vote.  From what I have seen, most of them either show the results after you place your vote, or show the results after you click the "See Results" button.

What would happen if on Stack Exchange, the voting results did not immediately appear for the answers?  (The vote count would still be immediately visible for the question.)  For example, where it has the number of votes an answer was received, it would be replaced with a button of some sort to show the votes when activated, or it would show the votes when a vote was placed.  The answers would still be sorted the same way.

I am sure this would drastically change the meta of Stack Exchange, but I don't know how.  One positive effect would be that snowball voting would be reduced, and this would lead towards more accurate vote counts.  What other metrics would likely be changed if Stack Exchange used this model instead?

*Please note, this is a discussion and not a feature request.*

Comment: showing votes after a vote was placed would prevent most users from being able to see votes and therefore from being able to easily assess the usefulness of answers.

Comment: @RobertLongson I edited question to say that the answered would still be sorted.  And the votes are still viewable without voting, just not by default.  But I see your point.  If I am looking at a question with 10 answers, I want to know how many of those answers are worth reading with as little effort as possible.

Answer (score 5):

The net effect would probably be negative.

The votes aren't there for the people voting, or for the purpose of sorting. They're also there for the people coming to the page looking for an answer, often because they Googled basically the same question. If there are five answers, with scores of {85, 73, 58, 4, -2}, that's a pretty strong signal that the first three answers are solid, and likely to actually help, whereas the last two are less likely to be of use. On the other hand, scores of {85, 8, 5, 0, -2} send a very different message; the answers past the first are either less likely to help, or probably just duplicating information.

And if the accepted answer has a lower score than the second answer, that's a strong signal that while the accepted one helped the actual question asker, more people in your situation (that is, coming to the question after the fact) were helped by the second answer.

Comment: You are basically right, but I think OP wants on honest assessment of the answer with 4 votes. Maybe it is new and didn't get as much eyes as the 85 scoring answer. Maybe the 4 scored answer is even better.

Comment: If it's new, the question just got bumped to the top of the active view on that site, and is getting views from people specifically evaluating that answer. And the date's plainly visible, just like the votes, because *we want visitors to have the information needed to help judge how useful an answer is*.

Comment: How often did you scroll down to see the 10th answer? Often I see spam hanging around here. If you were right, we shouldn't have that since enough people got to see it. Honestly, most users don't care.

Comment: @PatrickHofman "How often did you scroll down to see the 10th answer?" Honestly? Roughly as often as I encounter a question with ten answers, where by #10, they're still fairly well-scored, and not all just duplicating information. Not that that happens much outside meta sites.

Comment: I guess you are an exception compared to the average SE user.

Answer (score 0):

Showing the score makes users biased, and that is often something good. When you look for an answer to a question you have, the vote count is a indication of the number of people that found an answer useful. It doesn't say low-voted answers weren't useful. Maybe the highest voted answer is years old and it got much more eyes than the new low-voted (maybe eve better) answer.

With new questions, you often see users coming in and vote up the answer with the highest score. That isn't always the best answer, maybe the author was just the fastest gun. Hiding the score could prevent that. It will make the voting process a little more honest, maybe.

Despite that, I think hiding the post score isn't the solution to this 'problem'. It is a useful metric to most users from outside the network. We'd better educate voters than hide useful information.